# Что за среда разработки для sqlite на скриншоте?

Tags: sql, sqlite, ide

Пересмотрел несколько различных: sqlite administrator, manager, studio, manger(firefox), professional - не нашёл. Мне нравится, что здесь скрипты можно в виде вкладок сделать, как в Sql Server Management Studio. И ещё здесь отличный вывод, если в studio или firefox запускать несколько запросов разделённых ;, то на первой ошибке ломается, а в этом варианте нет. Главное - вкладки для скриптов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как-то я сомневаюсь, что вопросы типа «гадание по скриншоту» подходят для stackoverflow

Comment: @andreymal https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/Home/Databases/Engineering/about используется в видео по sql здесь.

Comment: Лучшая среда для баз данных это DataGrip от JetBrains
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/

Comment: В SQLiteStudio можно создавать сколько угодно окон для скриптов. "Вкладки" для них по умолчанию размещаются внизу (что не совсем удобно, да). Но их можно перетащить вверх и разместить почти где угодно.